# Consumer producer implementation involving POSIX, semaphores, and locks

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am trying to get over my fear of multithreading programming and teaching myself to code using POSIX. I wrote a small version of the consumer producer problem. I am hoping I can get some feedback if it works (I think it does, as I traced the threads when my `for` loop was at 20 and it made sense) and what I should do to improve my code.

The semaphore starts at 4, the consumer waits one second, and then consumes a semaphore.  The producer waits between 0 and 5 seconds, then produces (increments) the semaphore value. The consumer should wait if the semaphore is at 0 until the producer frees up the resources.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

sem_t my_semaphore;
pthread_mutex_t count_mutex;
void * consumerUse(void * ptr);
void * producerUse(void * ptr);

int main() {

    int value;
    pthread_t consumer, producer;
    int valConsumer =0;
    int valProducer =0;

    sem_init(&my_semaphore, 0, 4);
    sem_getvalue(&my_semaphore, &value);
    printf("The initial value of the semaphore is %d\n", value);

    for(int i=0; i < 100; i++)
    {

        valConsumer = pthread_create(& consumer, NULL, consumerUse, (void*)(intptr_t) value);
        if(valConsumer != 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error - pthread create () return code: %d\n", valConsumer);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        valProducer = pthread_create(& producer, NULL, producerUse, (void*) (intptr_t)value);
        if(valProducer != 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error - pthread create () return code: %d\n", valProducer);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

    }
    pthread_join( consumer, NULL);
    pthread_join( producer, NULL);
    printf("End program\n");
    return 0;
}

void *consumerUse(void * ptr)
{
    sleep(1);
    int value;
    sem_getvalue(&my_semaphore, &value);
    printf("Before wait: %d\n", value);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&count_mutex);
    sem_wait(&my_semaphore);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&count_mutex);
    sem_getvalue(&my_semaphore, &value);
    printf("Consumer semaphore value: %d\n", value);
    return 0;
}

void *producerUse(void * ptr)
{

    int pause = rand() % 5;
    sleep(pause);
    int value;
    sem_getvalue(&my_semaphore, &value);
    printf("Before post: %d\n", value);
    if(value < 4)
    {

        sem_post(&my_semaphore);
        sem_getvalue(&my_semaphore, &value);
        printf("Producer semaphore value: %d\n", value);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**General note**

It is very hard to tell if this program works or not: I don't know what is supposed to be a correct behaviour. I can only speculate that you didn't want to see a semaphore value ever to exceed 4. If it is the case, than it is a pure coincidence -- caused by the large delays (try to remove `sleep()`). Absolutely nothing in the code prevents two or more producers to "simultaneously" test the value, and proceed to post the semaphore.

**Particular problems**

There is no reason to serialize consumers' access to a `sem_wait()`. In a sense it defeats the purpose of the semaphore.

`stdio` is not thread safe. The fact that printouts haven't messed up is another coincidence, also caused by the `sleep()` delays.

The code creates a multitude of threads, but joins only two. Not a problem in a toy program; a bad resource leak in general.

A minor note: since the thread functions ignore the argument, you should pass `NULL`. Passing anything else (like `(void *) (intptr_t) value`) is misleading.

Comment: Can you be more specific about stdio not being thread safe.  I have read on several posts the stdio is an atomic operation.  Wouldn't that make it thread safe?

Comment: My wrong choice of words, sorry. It *is* thread safe in a sense that calling them from different threads wouldn't cause bad things such as memory corruption. However, they are not reentrant and/or atomic. See for example this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13190254/weird-output-when-i-use-pthread-and-printf

Comment: Makes sense, it seems that adding flockfile(stdout); before printf and funlockfile(stdout); after take care off that problem